# TestFlight App Download Error - "Could not load App"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, testflight, app-distribution

Hello StackOverflow community,

We are currently facing an issue with TestFlight while attempting to download our iOS app. Here is the sequence of events leading up to the problem:

1. Initially, we developed the app and conducted successful internal testing using TestFlight. No issues were encountered during this phase.
2. Encouraged by the positive results, we proceeded to test the app with external testers. However, our first attempt was met with rejection due to a missing demo login, which we promptly resolved.
3. Subsequently, we continued refining the build with our internal testers, and everything was functioning as expected.

However, after attempting to clear the cache by changing the app version, our testers started encountering an error message stating "Could not load App." We even reverted back to the previous version, but the problem persists.

We are currently unsure whether the issue is caused by the version change or the initial rejection of the build during external testing. As a remote team, this problem is significantly impacting our workflow and testing processes.

We would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance from the community. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? If so, what steps were taken to resolve it? We are open to any suggestions or recommendations that could help us overcome this challenge.

Thank you in advance for your valuable support.

Best regards,
Tejesh

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a very long unresolved issue from apple
for me when I faced this issue

```
            I removed My and others account from the test and added them again  for testing and it started working again
```

below link helped me

> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81435

Comment: Did you remove them from internal tester group or completly removed the user account?

Comment: removed everything actually! from user to groups

Comment: I tried removing from testers group, and it did not work. I will remove from the users and try again.

Comment: Did not work either.